# Format of data in PUT requests

Tags: ember.js

I am preparing my server-side application to handle `PUT` requests comming from an `emberjs` client (using `ember-data`). The client side application is not yet ready, so that I am not able to see the real requests (this in the hands of another developer). I nevertheless want to implement the server side. Where can I find information about the detailed format of `PUT` requests? I need two things:

1. What is the `emberjs` application going to send in the `URL`, `headers` and `body` of the request?
2. What is the `emberjs` application expecting as reply to the the `PUT` request?

[Here](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/) you can find a description of the REST interface which `emberjs` assumes, but I have been unable to find detailed information about `PUT` requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using ember-data's default RESTAdapter, the following is the default format:

Let's say you are updating a post with the following attributes:

```
id: 50,
title: 'PUT requests'
body: 'Ember-data has a lot of potential'
isPublished: false
```

The `PUT` request will be made to the URL: '/posts/50'.

the payload submitted in the `PUT` request will be in the following format:

```
{
  "post": {
    "id": 50,
    "title": "PUT requests",
    "body": "Ember-data has a lot of potential",
    "is_published": false
  }
}
```

The RESTAdapter expects the response to be in the same format as above.

Comment: Thanks. This is anyway a confusing use of "post" for an entity name (specially in a PUT request). I have seen a similar thing in the ember-data documentation, and wanted to mention it to the maintainers. I mean, for beginners in `ember-data`, *any* other entity name will cause less confussion.