# Format of data in POST requests

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

(this question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635328/format-of-data-in-put-requests))

I am sending POST requests to my server, which are being processed correctly: new objects are created in the database. This is the format I am using for the payload in the POST request:

```
{"node":{"type":null,"name":"sdfasfaf","outputs":null,"properties":null}}
```

To create a `node` object.

This is what the backend replies:

```
{"node": "64e11313-61eb-44ab-8ab8-1cbdf52304b4"}
```

Which is basically de `id` of the newly created entry. But `Ember` is not reacting to this reply: it stays on the "New Node" window. Worse still, the new node is added to the list of nodes, but Ember is not aware of the id of this node (which has been generated server-side).

Is there some place where I can find a detailed description of the payload of the POST requests, and of the expected reply format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

POST request payload

```
{
    "node":
    {
      "type":null,
      "name":"sdfasfaf",
      "outputs":null,
      "properties":null
    }
}
```

POST response payload

```
{
    "node":
    {
      "id":1,
      "type":null,
      "name":"sdfasfaf",
      "outputs":{},
      "properties":{}
    }
}
```

basically by simply returning the same json payload with the id set would work.
hope it helps...